# How to filter an array by checking if the current element id value equals any of the values within another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to loop through this array:

```
array = [
    Object {
        id=10,
        more irrelevant data
    },
    Object {
        id=11,
        more irrelevant data
    },
    Object {
        id=12,
        more irrelevant data
    },
    Object {
        id=13,
        more irrelevant data
    },
    Object {
        id=14,
        more irrelevant data
    },
]
```

and return the current element if the id of the current element is equal to one of the values in another array like this:

```
checkArray= [10, 53, 14]
```

In this case the objects with an id of 10 and an id of 14 will be returned.

So far I have written:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(function(currentElement) {
    if(currentElement.id == ???) {



        return currentElement
    }
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All you need is `return checkArray.includes(currentElement.id);`

Comment: Also, the filter function is supposed to return true or false.

Comment: You can also do it backwards: `const filteredArray = checkArray.map(id => array.find(item => item.id === id)).filter(item => item);` (the last part removes checkArray ids without a match)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
array = [{id:10},{id:11},{id:12},{id:13},{id:14}];
checkArray = [10, 53, 14];

//make a set
checkArraySet = new Set(checkArray);

//filter by the set 
let filteredArray = array.filter((currentElement) => checkArraySet.has(currentElement.id));

console.log(filteredArray)
```

also you should check out the docs on [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The return value of the passed function should be a Boolean. Passing the whole object will work because it is truthy but it's also pointless.